# Binding an event on page height changing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to execute a bit of javascript each time the height of the page changes.

So far, I'm doing something quite ugly : I use callback every time I do something that could change the page's height.

```
// initial 
positionFooter();
$(window).resize(positionFooter);

...
// some code in some function 
$(this).hide(0, positionFooter);
...

...
// some code in some function 
$(this).show(0, positionFooter);
...

...
// some code in some function 
toggle(i,p.speed, positionFooter);
...
```

I'd like to find a way where my function would be automaticly called when page height is changing. Do you have any ideas ?

Edit : it seems that my issue isn't clear : some events (change of tabs, ajax loading new content, toggle events, ...) do not trigger the resize function. To solve this problem, I chose to call the function manually after each one of these events. It works fine, but I don"t find that solution satisfying. It would be cleaner if there were a way to catch any page's height change in one place.

Comment: I don't see you using callbacks in the code above.

Comment: Every time the page's height changes, it fires the `resize` event. That's perfectly fine. What did you expect? On the other hand, I guess you're trying to stick the footer to the bottom of the windows. May I suggest to try harder with CSS?

Comment: @MaxArt: +1 I think you are correct, given the name of the function if re-positioning the footer is an on-goign battle CSS is probably something to take a closer look at for a solution.

Comment: I think I wasn't clear enough : sometimes, the page's height changes because of javascript events : ajax loading new content, tabs changing, show&hide animation... Those events don't trigger the resize event.

Answer (score 0):

With Jquery, $(window).resize(function) will call function everytime the window is resized.

```
$(window).resize(function() {
   //Do something when the window is resized
}
```

If you are trying to change CSS, you can use Media Queries directly in your CSS like this

```
@media only screen 
and (max-device-width : 1023px) {
/* Styles */
}

@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 1024px) {
/* Styles */
}
```

[Jquery.resize()](http://api.jquery.com/resize/) [Media Queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/)

If this does not answer your question please rephrase or give us some more info on the function you are calling / what browser you are testing in.

Comment: Well that's exactly how you do it. It must be an issue with the function being called.

Comment: Actually, ast didn't say the code wasn't working, just that was ugly. But I don't know how it can be better.

Comment: "I'd like to find a way where my function would be automaticly called when page height is changing. DO you have any ideas". Above code does that

Comment: @BrandenStilgarSueper: I think there is more than 1 issue. OP is already using that exact syntax which will work on page resize. I think the second problem, looking at the posted code, seems that when elements are hidden or shown, they don't necessarily trigger a page resize event, as such the same function has to be called manually as well. I think OP is looking for an overall auto-call but I think the question may have not been phrased correctly.